# If $z^n+z^{-n}=2\cos(n\theta)$ show that $5z^4-z^3-6z^2-z+5=0 => 10\cos^2(\theta)-\cos(\theta)-8=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> If $z^n+z^{-n}=2\cos(n\theta)$ show that $5z^4-z^3-6z^2-z+5=0 =>
> > 10\cos^2(\theta)-\cos(\theta)-8=0$.

I can prove $z^n+z^{-n}=2\cos(n\theta)$ with De Moivre's theorem (the sines cancel out and hence the result). But I don't know how I should apply this to this exercise. I don't know how should I get the corresponding $z^{-n}$ term for $z^n$ in this exercise. Maybe there is some relationship between the powers of complex roots? Could you help, please?

Comment: What if we add the needed on both the sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply your expression over $z^{-2}$
$$5z^2-z-6-z^{-1}+5z^{-2}=0$$
And using the property you mentioned $z^n+z^{-n}=2\cos(n\theta)$
$$10\cos(2\theta)-2\cos(\theta)-6=0$$
Finally, you can use expressions for the cosine of the double angle.

This solution has the functional form you are looking for, however the coefficients are not exactly the samen as in your result. Please, let me know if I made a mistake or I misunderstood something

Answer (score 1):

Same starting point, but computing in a slightly different way:
$$5z^2-z-6-z^{-1}+5z^{-2}=5(z+z^{-1})^2-10-(z+z^{-1})-6=20\cos^2\theta-2\cos\theta-16=0.$$